# SQL Server 2008 - WHILE Loop

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, while-loop, triggers, cursor

I have a problem that I can not solve, my final goal is to make a trigger that runs every time it is inserted in the 'factura' table and then fill an intermediate table that only has one field (varchar max), because ?, because I have a component in Java that reads this field and generates a file.txt that he later used, but I have a problem that I can not solve, I was seeing what could be with a cursor or better still with a while loop but I am entangled, the BD manager that I use is SQL Server 2008, the select query that I use to generate the data that will be filled in the intermediate table in the trigger, consists of two parts, the header and the details, which I seek to do is that it only shows one row per header, but since there are more than 1 detail in some cases it shows repeated rows.

This is my query:

```
select 
    --HEADER(CB),
    'CB' + '|' + CONVERT(varchar(10),(CONVERT(DATE, f.FECHA))) + '|' +
       '20601140897' + '|' + '03' + '|' +
       SUBSTRING(f.SERIE, 1, 2) + '0' + SUBSTRING(f.SERIE, 3, 2) + '-' + 
       REPLACE(STR(f.NUMERO, 8), SPACE(1), '0') + '|' + 
       CASE 
          WHEN f.CODIGO = '' THEN '99999999' 
          ELSE f.CODIGO 
       END + '|' + '0' + '|' +
       CASE 
          WHEN f.NOMBRE =''  THEN 'Clientes varios' 
          ELSE f.NOMBRE  
       END + '|PEN|' +
       CONVERT(varchar(13), (CAST(f.SUBTOTAL AS decimal(10, 2)))) + 
       '|0.00|0.00|' +
       CONVERT(varchar(13), (CAST(f.IMPUESTO AS decimal(10, 2)))) + 
       '|0.00|0.00|0.00|0.00|' +
       CONVERT(varchar(13), (cast(f.TOTAL as  decimal(10, 2)))) + '|0.00|0.00|' +
       'MONTO TOTAL' + '|||||||1000||||0.00|0.00|0.00||' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) +
  --DETAIL(DF)
  'DB' + '|' + 'NUMBER OF ROW' + '|' + d.PRODUCTO + '|' + 'NIU' + '|' + '1' + '|' +
     d.DESCRIPCIO + '|' + CONVERT(varchar(13),(ROUND((d.PRECIO/1.18), 2))) + '|' +
     CONVERT(varchar(13), (cast(d.PRECIO as decimal(10, 2)))) + '|' +
     CONVERT(varchar(13), (ROUND(((d.PRECIO/1.18) * 0.18), 2))) + '|10|0.00||' +
     CONVERT(varchar(13), (cast(d.TOTAL as decimal(10, 2)))) + '|0.00||0.00||'
FROM
    factura f 
FULL JOIN
    detalle d ON f.NUMERO = d.NUMERO 
FULL JOIN
    clientes c ON f.CODIGO = c.codigo
```

And this is what it shows:

> **CB**|2017-10-08|20601140897|03|B001-00002224|000700323|0|Clientes
>   varios|PEN|25.42|0.00|0.00|4.58|0.00|0.00|0.00|0.00|30.00|0.00|0.00|MONTO
>   TOTAL|||||||1000||||0.00|0.00|0.00||  **DB**|NUMBER OF
>   ROW|220|NIU|1|TODO EL
>   DIA|8.47|10.00|1.53|10|0.00||10.00|0.00||0.00||
>
> **CB**|2017-10-08|20601140897|03|B001-00002224|000700323|0|Clientes
>   varios|PEN|25.42|0.00|0.00|4.58|0.00|0.00|0.00|0.00|30.00|0.00|0.00|MONTO
>   TOTAL|||||||1000||||0.00|0.00|0.00||  **DB**|NUMBER OF
>   ROW|230|NIU|1|10 MIN FIN DE
>   SEMANA|16.94|20.00|3.06|10|0.00||20.00|0.00||0.00||

**What I look for:**

> **CB**|2017-10-08|20601140897|03|B001-00002224|000700323|0|Clientes
>   varios|PEN|25.42|0.00|0.00|4.58|0.00|0.00|0.00|0.00|30.00|0.00|0.00|MONTO
>   TOTAL|||||||1000||||0.00|0.00|0.00||  **DB**|NUMBER OF
>   ROW|220|NIU|1|TODO EL
>   DIA|8.47|10.00|1.53|10|0.00||10.00|0.00||0.00||  **DB**|NUMBER OF
>   ROW|230|NIU|1|10 MIN FIN DE
>   SEMANA|16.94|0.00|3.06|10|0.00||20.00|0.00||0.00||

Somebody could help me? or give me a structure to be able to achieve it, please, I'd be really grateful.

Comment: Can you share the table structure for factura, detalle, clientes  and sample records?

Comment: I pass a link to a backup that I just made to only those 3 tables, the DB does not have primary keys, since that's how I have to work it, but I hope you can help me.  https://mega.nz/#!9WREjLDJ!jPFU_aH-i77DBcxNr9fZ6r9HWZL08uyuiPN5WjWQBbA

Comment: Thanks Dalex!! This backup will help.

Comment: Did my answer help? If yes, please select as answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution, for the issue of performance, really only need the last record, since it will be a trigger that fills an intermediate table, I do not need to list all the concatenated records, so the xml path will serve me, it hurts that the STRING_AGG is not available in sql server 2008.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the query, which will append the detail data when there is an identical header data. Query is slow as it involves JOIN on string and large column, You can replace CTE with temp table and by adding index may give a better performance.

```
;WITH CTE AS (
select 
    --HEADER(CB),
    'CB' + '|' + CONVERT(varchar(10),(CONVERT(DATE, f.FECHA))) + '|' +
       '20601140897' + '|' + '03' + '|' +
       SUBSTRING(f.SERIE, 1, 2) + '0' + SUBSTRING(f.SERIE, 3, 2) + '-' + 
       REPLACE(STR(f.NUMERO, 8), SPACE(1), '0') + '|' + 
       CASE 
          WHEN f.CODIGO = '' THEN '99999999' 
          ELSE f.CODIGO 
       END + '|' + '0' + '|' +
       CASE 
          WHEN f.NOMBRE =''  THEN 'Clientes varios' 
          ELSE f.NOMBRE  
       END + '|PEN|' +
       CONVERT(varchar(13), (CAST(f.SUBTOTAL AS decimal(10, 2)))) + 
       '|0.00|0.00|' +
       CONVERT(varchar(13), (CAST(f.IMPUESTO AS decimal(10, 2)))) + 
       '|0.00|0.00|0.00|0.00|' +
       CONVERT(varchar(13), (cast(f.TOTAL as  decimal(10, 2)))) + '|0.00|0.00|' +
       'MONTO TOTAL' + '|||||||1000||||0.00|0.00|0.00||' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) HeaderData,
  --DETAIL(DF)
  'DB' + '|' + 'NUMBER OF ROW' + '|' + d.PRODUCTO + '|' + 'NIU' + '|' + '1' + '|' +
     d.DESCRIPCIO + '|' + CONVERT(varchar(13),(ROUND((d.PRECIO/1.18), 2))) + '|' +
     CONVERT(varchar(13), (cast(d.PRECIO as decimal(10, 2)))) + '|' +
     CONVERT(varchar(13), (ROUND(((d.PRECIO/1.18) * 0.18), 2))) + '|10|0.00||' +
     CONVERT(varchar(13), (cast(d.TOTAL as decimal(10, 2)))) + '|0.00||0.00||' DetailData
FROM    factura f FULL JOIN    detalle d ON f.NUMERO = d.NUMERO 
        FULL JOIN    clientes c ON f.CODIGO = c.codigo
    )

    select HeaderData+STUFF((SELECT '|'+ DetailData
                             FROM CTE C
                             WHERE C.HeaderData=T.HeaderData
                             FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'')
    FROM CTE T
    GROUP BY HeaderData
```